# How to rotate the pivot axis from vertex group named attribute

Tags: geometry-nodes

From reading from here manage to rotate the axis but it is in the wrong end  as you can see from the gif it's pivot is in the hand not in arm end....the geonode has a vertex group named attribute and want to rotate it in the arm end.....[image]

Comment: the center of the *vector rotate* is what you want to change

Comment: want the pivot relocate to the upper end not in the palm...want to rotate it like regular arm...